# HOW to determine machine endianness on windows XP- X86

Tags: windows

I am trying to install a software using MSYS and MinGW on Windows XP as I am knew to UNIX and UBUNTU. I installed Msys and MinGW, while I am setting up the build environment on  win32 by running the following cmd:

```
./setup.sh C:/SRC/NBIS/Main --MSYS --32
```

I am getting this error:

`gcc.exe: am_big_endian.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: no input files
/bin/setup.sh: line 221: ./am_big_endian: No such file or directory
Failed Setup - Cannot determine target machine endianness!`

What can I do to resolve the error?

Comment: Seeing how Windows XP x86 is little-endian-only, it's rather trivial to determine endianness (it's always the same!). If you want something portable, make a union of an `int` and a `char[4]` and set the `int` part to `1`. Then look where in the `char` array it comes out.

Comment: This question is about application installation, not programming. Your installation package is incomplete it is missing the file `am_big_endian.c`.

Answer (score 1):

x86-machines are always little-endian.